# Pytorch tracing - How do you trace a saved weight?

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch

I am trying to trace a saved weight I have so that I can load it with Catalyst. I checked the documentation on PyTorch, but I only found tracing on functions.

Comment: What is "tracing a weight"? What is "Catalyst"? This is not a common terminology.

Answer (score 0):

You can trace `torch.nn.Module` instances.

If you are not using data dependent flow control simply use `torch.jit.trace`, for example:

```
torch.jit.trace(module, example_input)
```

If it does, use `torch.jit.script`:

```
torch.jit.script(module)
```

You can find more info [inside tutorials](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/Intro_to_TorchScript_tutorial.html) or respective documentation.